# Using matplotlib *without* TCL

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tcl

Exactly what the title says. Is there a way to use the matplotlib library *without* installing TCL? Please don't tell me to bite the bullet and install TCL - I know how to do it but for my own (ok maybe silly) reasons I don't want to.

I don't care about displaying the plots, I only want to be able to output them in a png. I tried various things (using different backends etc) but matplotlib always wanted to find tcl to work :( Why is TCL so essential for matplotlib?

Also, please notice that I am using windows -- I have installed everything that could be required (numpy, pandas, matplotlib) using pip.

@gerrit's solution is the correct one (I was trying to change the backends but I was doing it *after* loading pyplot -- the important thing seems to be that you need to change the backend immediately after imporing matplotlib). Here's a small example using it:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots( nrows=1, ncols=1 )
ax.plot([0,1,2], [10,20,3])

fig.savefig('foo.png')
plt.close(fig)
```

This will output a file named 'foo.png' without using TCL \o/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Matplotlib 3.0 and newer

*(Added to answer in October 2018)*

Starting with Matplotlib 3, released on 19 September 2018, the problem described in the question should not occur.  From the [what's new part of the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.0.0/users/whats_new.html):

> The default backend no longer must be set as part of the build process. Instead, at run time, the builtin backends are tried in sequence until one of them imports.
>
> Headless linux servers (identified by the DISPLAY env not being defined) will not select a GUI backend.

So, as long as you make sure DISPLAY is not defined, you should not run into any problems with the backend when running in a script on a headless Linux server.

### Matplotlib 2.2 and older

*(Original answer May 2016)*

Immediately after loading matplotlib, enter

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Do this before loading `pyplot`, if at all.

By default, Matplotlib uses the `TkAgg` backend, which requires Tcl.  If you don't want to display the plots, `Agg` is fine.  Other alternatives include `WX` and `QTAgg`, but both require the installation of additional libraries.

Alternately, you can set this directive in your `matplotlibrc` file:

```
backend : Agg
```

For details, see the [Matplotlib Usage FAQ](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) on *What is a backend?*.

Comment: Yes it works ! I've updated my question with a small example of using your solution - thanks!